# Extension method that returns an the correct implementation of an interface?

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I am not sure if this is possible and I may need to write extension methods for each implementation. Here is some example code:

```
public interface IBaseService<T>
{
    IUnitOfwork UnitOfWork {get;}
}

public interface IService<T>: IBaseService<T>
{
    IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
    T GetById(Guid id);
}

public interface IUserService: IService<User>
{
     User FindByUsernameAndPassword(string username, string password)
}

public class BaseService<T>: IService<T>
{

     public BaseService(IRepository<T> repository)
     {
        _repository = repository
     }
     public virtual IEnumerable<T> GetAll(){....};
     public virtual T GetById(Guid id){....};
     IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork {get {return _repository.UnitOfWork;}}
}

public class UserService: BaseService<User>, IUserService
{
   ...
}

public static class ServiceExtensions
{
     public static IBaseService<T> EnableLazyLoading<T>(this IBaseService<T> service, bool lazyLoad = True)
     {
          service.UnitOfWork.EnableLazyLoad(lazyLoad);
          return service;
     }
}
```

So, let's say I am using the UserService. When I call the extension method on the UserService, is it possible to have it return the proper implementation of IBaseService or do I need to create and Extension Method for each implementation?:

Example:

```
userService.EnableLazyLoading(false).FindByUsernameAndPassword("ddivita","123456")
```

Comment: So, to clarify, are you saying you want it to create a new version of whatever it's called from?

Comment: I'd like only to write one extension method to be used by all implementations of IBaseServcie<T> that would return the correct implementation of it. In my example I'd like to figure out a way to return the IUserService when I call the EnableLazyLoading extension.

Comment: Oh!  I see, so you want it to return the specific type it was called in, not create a new instance of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
public static S EnableLazyLoading<T, S>(this S service, bool lazyLoad = true)
     where S : IBaseService<T>
{
     service.UnitOfWork.EnableLazyLoad(lazyLoad);
     return service;
}
```

Comment: I came up with the same answer, only problem is it can't infer the type (which may or may not be okay with the OP), so you'd have to explicitly call it like: `userService.EnableLazyLoading<UserService, User>(false)...`

Comment: Yes, that's true, but i would prefer this way over creating a extension method n times. The only thing you could do, if you have multiple extension methods, is to change from a interface to a abstract class.

Comment: Sad thing is, if we could assume the `T` (i.e. in his example assume the `User`) then inference could kick in...

Answer (score 2):

Okay, this may or may not work with your design, but it builds on Felix's answer (which he should get the credit for) and makes it infer-able.

Because your `UnitOfWork` class does not depend on type `T`, you can create an `IBaseService` that is non generic that contains the `UnitOfWork` member, then make `IBaseService<T>` extend `IBaseService` like so:

```
public interface IBaseService
{
    // all non-type-T related stuff
    IUnitOfwork UnitOfWork {get;}
}

public interface IBaseService<T> : IBaseService
{
    // .. all type T releated stuff
}
```

Then, keep rest of your class design as normal and write the extension method as:

```
public static S EnableLazyLoading<S>(this S service, bool lazyLoad = true)
     where S : IBaseService
{
     service.UnitOfWork.EnableLazyLoad(lazyLoad);
     return service;
}
```

Since we don't need the `IBaseService<T>` to get `UnitOfWork` now, we don't need to specify the second type parameter `T` which was making inference problematic.  So now we can write the code exactly as you wanted because it can now infer `S` is `UserService` without needing to know about the type `T` (`User`):

```
userService.EnableLazyLoading(false).FindByUsernameAndPassword("ddivita","123456");
```

Of course, this is assuming, as I said, that `UnitOfWork` doesn't need anything from type `T`.

As I said, @Felix deserves the answer, but just wanted to expand on how could make it infer-able to avoid having to pass in the generic type parameter.  Up-votes are appreciated though :-)

Comment: @DDiVita: Thanks, though like I said Felix deserves the answer, I was just building on his work.

Comment: This worked great, btw. My UoW is not typed, so it was a perfect solution. Thanks to you and Felix